# Htaccess causing sever error when rules are combined

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I add the following rule to my `.htaccess`, it works.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When I add the following rule, without the one above, it also works.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1&p2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

However, when I use both rules together, with the second before the first, I get an `Internal Server Error`.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the first rule also rewrites /index.php to itself.

You need to use a negitive lookahead based regex to exclude the /index.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1&p2=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: A simple RewriteCond can be used as well, no real “need” for negative lookahead.